# While Loop doesn't break when enter (return) key is pressed

Tags: python, while-loop

The program below is a dice simulator using the random library written in Python3. It randomly selects 1 digit out of 6 numbers that are there on a dice.

```
import random
while True:
    pipe = input("Type y to roll the dice ")
    if pipe in ('y'):
        numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        x = random.choice(numbers)
        print (x)
    else:
        print ("GoodBye")
        break
```

**Problem:** When I press the enter (return) key upon execution the program is using the 'y' case and giving out a random value and not ending (breaking the loop) the program. Why is that?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Comment: `('y')` -> `('y',)`. Or just use `==`.

Comment: Probably should use a set, not a tuple... `{'y'}` @Rawing

Comment: @Rawing `('y')` is the same as `'y'` so it really doesn't matter

Comment: @cricket_007 makes no difference when data struct has so few elements

Comment: what about pipe is 'y'

Comment: I just figured out @Rawing comment. ('y') is just parentheses around 'y' so it is the same as 'y' by itself and for some reason '' in 'y' is True.

Comment: If you type `y` then you don't do a break, you only `break` if you type something else.  If you *always* want to break then why use a loop?  Or do you have the `break` in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press `return`, the input is an empty string.  This is found in any string at all, so your check is still `True`: you did a character check on a string.  You might have extended this with

```
if pipe in "Yy":
```

This would catch either upper- or lower-case `Y`, but still fails to terminate on an empty string.

As others have suggested, use a different check, so you're looking for a whole_string match:

```
if pipe in ['y', 'Y']:
```

Comment: or use `if pipe and pipe in "Yy":`, this should do.

Answer (score 0):

Change the if condition to

```
if pipe is 'y':
```